# how to loop in comma seperated values in sql server, my loop mis last value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

suppose I have following sql code

```
DECLARE @colsLoop AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ='[Khulna Titans],[Rajshahi Kings]';
declare @pos as numeric = 0;
declare  @len as numeric = 0;
declare @value as varchar(255);


WHILE CHARINDEX(',',  @colsLoop, @pos+1)>0

BEGIN
set @len = CHARINDEX(',', @colsLoop, @pos+1) - @pos
set @value = SUBSTRING(@colsLoop, @pos, @len)

print @value

set @pos = CHARINDEX(',', @colsLoop, @pos+@len) +1
end
```

I cant figure it out  why this code only print [Khulna Titans] , I want it print [Rajshahi Kings] after [Khulna Titans], in other words why loop runs only once. Where do I mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL split string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your loop stops is because the loop processes once for each comma found in the string. You have only one comma in the string, so it processes just the first item. If you want it to process both strings you would need to add a comma to the end of the string.

Or print the remaining portion of the string after you exit the loop if it is not possible to add a comma to the end of the string.

hth